# "Ambiguous use" in Xcode 10, Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using a library [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) which is a Material Design drop down for `iOS` written in `Swift`.

I am setting `cornerRadius` of the view like below as DropDown is a subclass of `UIView`.

```
let dropDown = DropDown()
dropDown.cornerRadius = 10
```

It was working fine in `Xcode 9.4` but after upgrading to `Xcode 10` it is giving the error below:

> Ambiguous use of cornerRadius

what can be the issue?

Comment: Are you the one who opened [this issue](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown/issues/192)?

Comment: check this line https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown/blob/master/DropDown/src/DropDown.swift#L225 , What is  use the DropDown version ?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the library? Seems they added 4 days ago some Swift 4.2 related changes.

Answer (score 1):

As per your description you are trying to set cornerRadius for UIView which is not directly apply on a view. You can set for UIView like this:

```
let view = UIView()
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Now for the DropDown library:

To set cornerRadius in DropDown you need to set the appearance like this:

```
let appearance = DropDown.appearance()
appearance.cornerRadius = 10
```

You can find the sample in DropDown library to set its appearance.

Comment: did you test it with Xcode 10? 
I am getting "Ambiguous use of cornerRadius" there... with your solution

Comment: Yes, I test the sample in XCode 10, with simulator iPhone XS

Comment: Problem seems in your import statement, Did you use any other library as well in code like "import Material"? If yes just try to comment that.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your dropdown version to the latest with : pod update DropDown

Others are having the same issue as you are :

https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown/issues/192

Just wait until they fix it